# Why can't global variables and parameter variables in a constructor have the same name?

Tags: java, eclipse

```
public class ListNode {
ListNode next;
int data;

ListNode (int data) {
    next = null;
    this.data = data;
}
```

the above code works.

```
    public class Node<E> implements Position<E> {
    private E element;
    private Node<E> left, right, parent;

    public Node<E> (E element, Node<E> parent, Node<E> left, Node<E> right) {

    }
}
```

this one doesn't.

I realized that it's because constructors can't include the generic type declaration, or however it's called. The `<E>` shouldn't be in the constructor.

Comment: It's quite hard to understand the question as it's currently worded. Could you include the actual part of the class that causes the error and the exact error please?

Comment: This is so silly. I just realized that constructors can't include the generic type in their field. Sorry for wasting your time, people. I was going to remove this post but maybe it'll serve some other people in the future when they are having a similar problem remembering Java basics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the parameter `E` in the declaration as there is no need for it because it already exists in the type definition:

```
Node(E e, Node<E> parent, Node<E> left, Node<E> right)
```

Comment: thanks, realized this mistake almost immediately after I made my post.